# Two column TPopupMenu to list shortcuts right aligned

Tags: c++, c++builder, delphi-2009

Using Borland/CodeGear/Ebarcadero C++ Builder 2009.  Is it possible to show shortcuts (or other text), right aligned in a second column in a TPopupMenu ?

For instance:

```
[image] Open File        ctrl-O
[image] Close File       ctrl-W
[image] BlahBlah         ctrl-B
```

etc.

If so, how ?
I checked the break property on an item, but the results is not exactly what I want, since items are selectable on their own, instead of the complete line.  Also it's not drawn that nicely.

Your feedback appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A menu item can have an image (see the `TMenuItem.ImageIndex` property), and can have a shortcut assigned (see the `TMenuItem.ShortCut` property).  The VCL will automatically draw those elements for you, exactly as you have shown.

[image: menu1]

By default, they are a little squished together.  You can use the `TMenuItem.OnMeasureItem` event to extend the `Width`:

[image: menu2]

If you still do not like the way the default drawing looks, or you want different text than the `ShortCut` to appear on the right side, you will have to owner-draw the menu items yourself (see the `TMenuItem.OnDrawItem` and `TMenuItem.OnAdvancedDrawItem` events), then you can make the menu items appear however you want.

Comment: Great ! I did not know about the `TMenuItem.ShortCut` property.  I handle all shortcuts in a FormKeyDown event (the Form's KeyPreview is true).  The shortcuts long in place, I never bothered to display them as text, now I want to do that.  If I understand correctly VCL will now want to execute the MenuItem assigned shortcuts as well ?  This will lead to conflicts (not tested) ?  Is there a setting to make sure only the FormKeyDown is executed, yet the shortcut text remains displayed ?

Comment: Yes, if you assign a `ShortCut`, you do not need to handle the keystrokes manually, the VCL will handle the shortcut dispatching for you.

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a way to stop VCL doing that, as I'd like to simply keep using the Form's KeyDown event.  Actually, I just found: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/AppEvnts_TApplicationEvents_OnShortCut.html  (Setting `Handled` to `true` should do just that).  To be tested on Monday.